# How to transpose select list option values using jQuery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, selectlist

I currently have the following select list:

```
<select name="input_3" id="input_2_3" class="medium gfield_select" tabindex="3">
    <option value=" ">-- Select an Image --</option>
    <option value="mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/wedding_3.jpg">wedding 3</option>
    <option value="mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/wedding_2.jpg">wedding 2</option>
    <option value="mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/wedding_1.jpg">wedding 1</option>
</select>
```

Using this current select/drop-down list together with jQuery, how can I transpose this select list, within a document.ready function, to instead have everything between the `<select>...</select>` tags instead, look like:

```
<select name="input_3" id="input_2_3" class="medium gfield_select" tabindex="3">
    <option value=" ">-- Select an Image --</option>
    <option value="wedding 3" title="mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/wedding_3.jpg">wedding 3</option>
    <option value="wedding 2" title="mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/wedding_2.jpg">wedding 2</option>
    <option value="wedding 1" title="mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/wedding_1.jpg">wedding 1</option>
</select>
```

Basically, what use to be value="mysite.com/..." should now be title="mysite.com/..." and value should now equal the option label, such as "wedding 3".

Note: I want to ignore the first `<option>` where the value= " " as I need this to stay the same.

Comment: Can you post your attempts at solving this problem?

Comment: I tried some attempts using .each() as well as .replaceAll but unable to achieve what I was after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic solution that relies on the form of [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr) that takes a function:

```
$(".gfield_select > option:gt(0)").attr("title", function() {
    return this.value;
}).attr("value", function() {
    return $(this).text();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your examples are confusing me a little, but if I am reading correctly, you need to use jQuery's .attr() function, which allows you to alter attributes such as title, and the .val() function, which lets you change the elements value.

For example:

```
$("option").attr("title","url").val("url");
```

See the jQuery documentation of .attr() (http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and .val() (http://api.jquery.com/val/).

**Update**

If I understand you correctly, you first want to give the title attribute the value of... value, and then make value equal the text of that option.

```
$("option").each(function()
{
    $(this).attr("title", this.value).val($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: I think I may have confused you with my sentence at the end and so have removed it. Basically, what use to be value="mysite.com/..." should now be title="mysite.com/..." and value should now equal the option label. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: So, you just want to switch the "title" and "value" values round?

Comment: Replace(value="mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/wedding_3.jpg" to now be title="mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/wedding_3.jpg") as well assign value="wedding 3"

Comment: Updated, how's that? I'm unable to test it with any reliability unfortunately. If you want further help I'd need you to put it into a JSFiddle :(.